# Wired network loses connectivity, gets fixed after restart

Tags: networking, fedora, lan

I'm using Fedora 37 on a desktop computer. More detailed system info at the end of the question. The system randomly loses connectivity (shows a yellow excalamation mark with "limited connecivity" message) on the wired connection (wireless keeps working). Disconnecting and reconnecting the wired network does not fix that. Only restart fixes that.

- **Question 1**: How can I see the logs that show why this happens?
- **Question 2**: Is there a way to fix this without a full restart?

##### System info:

```
Operating System: Fedora Linux 37
KDE Plasma Version: 5.26.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.101.0
Qt Version: 5.15.7
Kernel Version: 6.0.12-300.fc37.x86_64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 32 × AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16-Core Processor
Memory: 30.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: ASUS
```

Motherboard is: `ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI`

Answer (score 1):

Could be a few things.

- First check and swap out the current network cable, might be a
  physical defect. Or use another PC on the same cable to verify.
- Could be a bad port on a router or switch in between. Again test with
  another PC or bypass it to see if the problem persists.
- Issues with drivers, for example Realtek NIC's can give you an
  array of weird issue. Check out various system logs starting with
  *dmesg* to see if anything weird pops up. Another way to rule this out is
  to boot up a recent Ubuntu live USB (Or any modern distro) and see if that works
  correctly, then you might be on to something.
- Issues with DHCP, try setting a static IP to rule out any problems
  regarding DHCP.
- If nothing works swap out your NIC and go for a proper brand :)

This is all I can guess/recommend based on the limited information here.

Answer (score 1):

`$ grep Link /var/log/kern.log`
...will get you some extra info on most systems, not sure about Fedora 37.  See what the link is doing, then just scan the log at relevant times for additional information around the event.

`$ sudo systemctl restart network`
...will restart (all) of your networking so if it's a software issue, that should bring your wired connection back up.  But you really want to find out why this is happening and address that, rather than just resetting the Ethernet every time it drops out.